# How to get Lat Long on Map Tap in Flutter?

Tags: google-maps, flutter

Can someone tell me how get latitude and longitude on map tap in flutter. Do I need to use any plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you mean is that you want a latitude/longitude to be displayed when you tap on some location on a Google Maps widget? In that case, check out the `place_picker` plugin. From the readme, it sounds like what you need. Link: https://pub.dev/packages/place_picker

**Edit:**
If you just want the latitude/longitude of any arbitrary location on the map, you can also do the following in your Google Map constructor itself:

```
GoogleMap(
  // all the other arguments
  onTap: (latLng) {
    print('${latLng.latitude}, ${latLng.longitude}');
  }
);
```

Comment: yeah that is what I want.

Comment: please check my updated answer for an easier, no-plugin way of doing this

Answer (score 0):

If you need a Lat and lang as well other property you have to use [place_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/place_picker) package. This package help you to get data from users selected location. Try This Code

```
Widget _dropDownButton() {
    return Positioned(
        top: 40,
        right: 15,
        left: 15,
        child: Container(
          height: 50,
          child: TextFormField(
            readOnly: true,
            enableInteractiveSelection: false,
            // will disable paste operation
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
            onChanged: (location) {
              setState(() {
                currentAddress = location;
              });
            },
            controller: locationController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              prefixIcon: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) {
                        return PlacePicker(
                          apiKey: kGoogleApiKey,
                          initialPosition: currentPostion,
                          useCurrentLocation: true,
                          selectInitialPosition: true,
                          usePlaceDetailSearch: true,
                          onPlacePicked: (result) {
                            setState(() {
                              selectedPlace = result;
                              locationController.text =
                                  selectedPlace.formattedAddress;
                              controllers.animateCamera(
                                CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
                                  CameraPosition(
                                      target: LatLng(
                                          result.geometry.location.lat,
                                          result.geometry.location.lng),
                                      zoom: 20.0),
                                ),
                              );
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            });
                          },
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                },
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.add_location,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  size: 20,
                ),
              ),
              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black54,
              ),
              hintText: 'Please choose a Address',
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
```